# AWS .NET SDK configure S3 Client with ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

**Tools**

- Visual Studio 2017 Professional
- .NET Core SDK v2.2.102
- AWSSDK.S3 v3.3.102.14

**What I'm trying to do**

Configure the Amazon S3 client for a development environment which uses a localstack endpoint as the ServiceURL for S3

I'm trying to configure the S3 client globally in my `Startup.cs` file using ASP.NET Core's native Dependency Injection

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
}
```

**Problem**

I can't figure out how to set the ServiceURL for the S3 Client.  I've seen in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html) that you can configure this property in the the `appsettings.json` file.  However, this wouldn't resolve my problem because I have multiple AWS services I need to integrate with.

Everything I've googled suggests you just need to do something like this:

```cs
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new AmazonS3Config
{
    ServiceURL = "http://localhost:5002"
});
```

But I would have to do this in every class that uses the S3 client, which doesn't seem right.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so I think I figured this one out.

Instead of using the built in ASP.NET Core DI:

```cs
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

I'm using Autofac like so ([docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html)):

```cs
var s3Config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    ServiceURL = _configuration.GetSection("AWS:ServiceURL").Value,
    ForcePathStyle = true
};

builder.RegisterType<AmazonS3Client>()
    .As<IAmazonS3>()
    .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(AmazonS3Config), s3Config))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add a package reference to `AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup`.  This give you access to some extension methods to help you setup AWS services in .NET Core DI.

```
services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(config.GetAWSOptions());
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>();
```

You can then start LocalStack with the `edge` service enabled and set the `PORT_EDGE_HTTP` env var.

```
PORT_EDGE_HTTP=50234 SERVICES=edge,s3,sqs localstack start
```

This allows you to use the same `ServiceURL` for all services offered by LocalStack instead of the various service-specific URLs running on their own ports.  This can be set via `appsettings.json`.

```
{
    "AWS": {
        "ServiceURL": "http://localhost:50234"
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** One thing I'm still trying to figure out is how to set `ForcePathStyle` via `appsettings.json`. AWS doesn't need this set, but apparently LocalStack does (for now, at least).

Answer (score 3):

For multiple `AmazonS3Client`, you could configure multiple `IAmazonS3` like

1. `IAmazonS3`

   ```
   public interface IAmazonS3A: IAmazonS3
   {
   }
   public interface IAmazonS3B : IAmazonS3
   {
   }
   ```
2. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3A>(Configuration.GetAWSOptions("AWSA"));
   services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3B>(Configuration.GetAWSOptions("AWSB"));
   ```
3. `appsettings.json`

   ```
   {
   "AWSA": {
       "Profile": "local-test-profile",
       "Region": "us-west-2"
   },
   "AWSB": {
       "Profile": "local-test-profile",
       "Region": "us-west-2"
   },
   }
   ```

Comment: yeah fair point, I've since run into a problem with localstack (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1014) that means I need to set the `ForecPathStyle` attribute to `true`.  I don't think this can only be done by instantiating the `AmazonS3Client` type and passing it an `AmazonS3Config` object... unless I've missed something??

Answer (score -1):

(forl colac s3 stack)
add nugget package:
"AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup"

in your Program.cs add:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(configuration.GetAWSOptions());
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>();
```

in your appsettings.json:

```
        "AWS": {
    "Region": "eu-west-1",
    "ServiceURL": "http://localhost:50234"
  },
```